# Can not add the same measure twice on Python unit test report

Tags: python, unit-testing, sonarqube

After upgrade to the following versions:

Sonar 5.2

Sonar Runner 2.4

Python Plugin 1.5

my test reports are not being processed correctly when I have more than one test file in the same package, for example:

**TEST-notas_leitores.tests.NotasLeitoresModelsTest-20160107114942.xml 

TEST-notas_leitores.tests.PaginaNotasLeitoresTest-20160107114942.xml**

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Sonar During Error runner execution
ERROR: Unable to run Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Can not add the same measure twice on org.sonar.api.resources.File@b497091[key=notas_leitores/tests.py,path=notas_leitores/tests.py,filename=tests.py,language=Python]: org.sonar.api.measures.Measure@27d4561[metricKey=skipped_tests,metric=Metric[id=<null>,key=skipped_tests,description=Number of skipped unit tests, type = INT, direction = -1, domain = Tests, name = Skipped unit tests,qualitative=true,userManaged=false,enabled=true,worstValue=<null>,bestValue=0.0,optimizedBestValue=true,hidden=false,deleteHistoricalData=false],value=0.0,data=<null>,description=<null>,alertStatus=<null>,alertText=<null>,date=<null>,variation1=<null>,variation2=<null>,variation3=<null>,variation4=<null>,variation5=<null>,url=<null>,characteristic=<null>,requirement=<null>,personId=<null>,persistenceMode=FULL,fromCore=false]
```

If these test results are removed, the analysis is done normally.

It works in Sonar 4.2 and Python Plugin 1.3.

My sonar-project.properties:

```
sonar.projectKey=key
sonar.projectName=name
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=module, test
sonar.language=py
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.python.coverage.reportPath=coverage.xml
sonar.python.xunit.reportPath=xmlrunner/TEST-*.xml
sonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
sonar.python.xunit.skipDetails=false
sonar.python.codeCoveragePlugin=cobertura
```

Answer (score 0):

It is valid to import several test report files. However, they should not contain results (e.g. number of failed tests) for the same test files.
This is the case here for `notas_leitores/tests.py`. Such a case is not accepted by SonarQube: if the results are different, which ones are correct?

If it works with SonarQube 4.2 with the same configuration, I suppose that this older version does not do the same checks and therefore does not show you that there is a problem with your setup.